# How To Create A Simple GUI For Taking 2 Excel Files and Uploading Them Into My Script

Tags: python, excel, pandas, user-interface, pysimplegui

I have a script that takes two excel files with two datasets and concatenates them and transforms various aspects of the resulting single data frame. I created this script in Jupyter Notebook. I want the person I am building this for to be able to utilize this script without having to interact with the Python. I am trying to figure out how to create a GUI that browses through one's files and allows you to bring in the two excel sheets, and then passes them to the script to be brought in as dataframes.

Currently I have some code copied from PySimpleGUI that allows me to browse and select two files. However I still am not sure how to pass the inputs from the GUI to my original script for transformation. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

'''

## Read in excel sheets

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
```

#### GUI Code from PySimpleGUI

```
sg.theme('Light Blue 2')

layout = [[sg.Text('Enter 2 files to comare')],
          [sg.Text('File 1', size=(8, 1)), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Text('File 2', size=(8, 1)), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]
print(layout[2])
window = sg.Window('File Compare', layout)

event, values = window.read()
window.close()

print(f'You clicked {event}')
print(layout[2])
```

## Original Code

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/mcket747-es/Documents/highschoolData/Fall Spring 2019 Summer 2020 Number 3 .xls")

df2 = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/mcket747-es/Documents/highschoolData/Summer 2019 Number 3.xls")
```

## Merge/Concatenate the dataframes & drop any duplicate roecords

```
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_merged.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to create a *mainloop* instead of a one-shot window. Plus you should work with more complicated layout with a button for each operation and their write backend codes to allow user to do several operations like merge, crop etc.

Have a look at
[PySimpleGUI Cookbook - Persistent Window](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/#recipe-pattern-2b-persistent-window-multiple-reads-using-an-event-loop-updates-data-in-window)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('Light Blue 2')

layout = [[sg.Text('Enter 2 files to comare')],
          [sg.Text('File 1', size=(8, 1)), sg.Input(key='Input_1'), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Text('File 2', size=(8, 1)), sg.Input(key='Input_2'), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]

window = sg.Window('File Compare', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Cancel"):
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        file_1, file_2 = values['Input_1'], values['Input_2']
        if '' not in [file_1, file_2]:
            # You may need more checks if files exist, if excel files, ...
            # do Excel job here.
            pass

window.close()
```